# How to verify if paperclip is working correctly with ImageMagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I installed ImageMagick and the paperclip gem on my Windows machine. The thing is that `:styles => {...}` is not working, so I assumed that paperclip is having some problem with ImageMagick.

I tested whether ImageMagick has been properly installed by running the `echo %path%` command and the installation seems to be alright.

I also included the following in the `development.rb` file:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.6.8-Q16"
```

In `show.html.erb`, the thumbnails are not displayed.

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:small) %>
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
```

How will I know that paperclip is not working with ImageMagick on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting an image with Imagemagick right from the command line:
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php?ImageMagick=j0e25rle0cl99l8lade2e6l8n3

if it doesn't work then it's your Imagemagick installation which is not working.

Also check if the image was created properly by rails, that should be in public/system/avatar/ folder inside you rails application folder, unless you changed the default configuration...

Comment: Converting an image with Imagemagick seems to work. If I remove the :styles => {...} in the user.rb, the image is saved in 'public/system/avatars' folder' But when i add the styles in the user.rb file such that :   has_attached_file :avatar,
    :styles => {  :thumb => "75x75>",
                  :small => "150x150>"
                }
, I get some error message.

Comment: Did you install the rmagick gem, so Rails can communicate with Imagemagick... this could be it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you put `form_for(...,:html => { :multipart => true })`? One day this helped me

Comment: yes, i did include this part. I get the inpression that paperclip gem is not detecting Imagemagick, although i included 'Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.6.8-Q16"' in the development.rb file

Answer (score 0):

I might be late here to give answer but this really help me to check if my imagemagick is working or not on which rmagick is depend. Just try to convert one of your image with

`convert rose.jpg -resize 50% rose.png`

This is just the basic operation for image magick. If it works for you then your imagemagick is working well